# Display Rss items in ListView

Tags: android, rss-reader

I am a new in Android developing and I am creating Rss Reader for Android, but I don't know how to display multiple rss items in ListView separately for every clicked rss feed. I'm sorry if I am not explained my question very well. I will appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to go would be to put your RSS items in a SQL Database and read them to your ListView. Here is a good example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm [Here][1]. Sends and retrieves data with HTTP that you can later set into a TextView i.e ( ListView )
You can send a response say ?rsscat=Sports POST or GET and have your PHP page retrieve it and update your ListView.